# Rename and Move Folders Using VB

Tags: vbscript

I have the following script which works great if I need to rename files in a folder but now I want to move and rename folders from one mapped drive to another mapped drive. Can someone help me to modify the script to do so? I am failry new to VB so pardon if I can't firgure this out but it took me a little while to figure this one out and now I am not sure how to modify this script. Thank you in advance!

The folders by default are labeled A.1234, A.5678, and so on and will always have a different number assigned to them. I will keep the numbers in the label as they are PO numbers. So my end result desired is Ack~1234, Ack~5678, and so on.

```
Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s Set 
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set f = fso.GetFolder("Y:\Test") 
Set fc = f.Files 
For Each f1 in fc 
    f1.move f1.ParentFolder & "\" & replace(f1.Name, "A.", "Ack~")
```

Again these folders exist on the root of a mapped drive and need to move to another mapped drive with the new names. If more info is needed please do not hesitate to ask.

**UPDATE**

I modified the script below to give an idea of what I'm looking to do.

```
Dim fso, objFol 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFol = fso.GetFolder("Z:\") 
Set objFolders = objFol.Folders 
For each folder in objFolders 
    fso.Movefolder folder, "Y:\" & Replace(fso.Name, "A.", "Ack~") 
Next
```

This give me an error stating it does not support "Folder". There will be any number of folders in the Z drive and I need to move them all to the Y drive. Sorry if I didn't explain properly in the previous post.

Comment: Looks like this is neither vb.net nor VBA nor VB, but VBScript. If am right, please change your tags.

Comment: Could be VBA or VB without Option Explicit (which is defaulted off for some reason I'll never understand). Have removed the vb.net tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The move command is taking a string, for which you're providing the parent folder of the file, so the file isn't moving. I think it'll be sufficient to provide a different folder location. For example:

```
Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set f = fso.GetFolder("Y:\Test") 
Set fc = f.Files 

For Each f1 in fc 
    f1.move "Z:\TargetFolder\" & replace(f1.Name, "A.", "Ack~")
```

Note: I've not tested this, but if there are problems then just ask

**Additional Stuff after update:**

The following code will allow you to move folders, and do the replacements you need to the folder name string.

```
Dim fso, objFol, objMoveFol, strPathBuild

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFol = fso.GetFolder("Y:\Test")

For Each objMoveFol In objFol.SubFolders

    'Replace the root folder locations in the path
    strPathBuild = Replace(objMoveFol, "Y:\Test", "Z:\TargetFolder\")

    'Do the required other fiddle
    strPathBuild = Replace(strPathBuild, "A.", "Ack~")

    fso.Movefolder objMoveFol, strPathBuild 

Next
```

Make sure you're really careful with this sort of thing, as getting is wrong can be fairly spectacular.

Comment: Jon, You have no idea how much I appreciate your response! I modified the script below to give an idea of what I'm looking to do. 

dim fso,objFol

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set objFol = fso.GetFolder("Z:\") 
set objFolders = objFol.Folders 
For each folder in objFolders 
 fso.Movefolder folder, "Y:\" & Replace(fso.Name, "A.", "Ack~")
Next 

This give me an error stating it does not support "Folder". 

There will be any number of folders in the Z drive and I need to move them all to the Y drive. Sorry if I didn't explain properly in the previous post.

Comment: Jon, I want to thank you once again for your feedback.  This works like a charm.  It even moves the files contained within the folders!  I tested the script locally and all is well. I attempted to to do so on the mapped drives and it failed due to permission rights. I will take this up with the server administrator and resolve that issue ASAP.  I truly appreciate your help with this!  Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem. If you like that much then hit the tick against my answer and I get extra Brownie points (as will you!)

Comment: Jon, I am getting a "permission denied" error when running the script. I am trying to move folders to a server which is mapped from the computer running the process.  Do I need to insert a script with credentials to ensure access?  Please advise and thanks in advance!